# MongoDB - How do I validate document field to only allow a specific file extension?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Is there a good way to validate the `file` field to only allow strings that end in ".gci"?  Not sure if I can do this directly in the schema or if I should just handle it somewhere else.

**schema.js:**

```
 const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      file: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide a .gci file"],
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#SchemaType.prototype.validate()) like so:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  file: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide a .gci file"],
    validate: {
       validator: function(v) {
           if (!value.endsWith(".gci")) {
               return false;
           }
       },
       message: props => `${props.value} doesn't end with .gci extension!`
    }
});
```